# Trying to plot equal height stacked barplot from already normalized relative abundance values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to create equal-height stacked barplots from normalized data (X-axis range 0-1). I have plotted the same as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=ids, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold")
  )
p + labs( y= "Relative_abundance", x= "Patients_ids") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Phylum")+ coord_flip()
```

All good and precisely what I wanted.
Now if I use the same script on a similar file (with minor adjustments according to header descriptions), I am getting stacked barplot of unequal lengths (see the code below):

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(data=df2, aes(factor(state_time))) +
  geom_bar (aes(group = variable, fill=variable)) + theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold")
  )
p + labs( y= "Relative_abundance", x= "Soil_Types") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Taxon")+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+ coord_flip()
```

How can I plot the same-heightened stacked barplot with 0-1 relative abundance range from df2?
Thanks a lot for your consideration.

Comment: You can include `position = "fill"` to get proportional stacked bars. e.g. `geom_col(position = "fill")`

Comment: Well, in your second code you use `geom_bar`. Hence you get a bar chart showing the counts of state_time. Perhaps you want `ggplot(data = df2, aes(state_time, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_col()` as you did in your first code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by converting columns into factors. Thanks everyone for your help.